# Zend Framework User agent Issue

Tags: zend-framework, jquery-mobile, user-agent

I am using Zend Framework 1.11.3 and Jquery 1.3.0 beta for my mobile web application.I have reffered to "http://juriansluiman.nl/en/article/111/mobile-detection-with-zend_http_useragent"  for checking if the user agent is mobile and used the following code :

```
    $frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
    $bootstrap       = $frontController->getParam('bootstrap');
    if (!$bootstrap->hasResource('useragent')) {
        throw new Zend_Controller_Exception('The mobile plugin can only be loaded when              the UserAgent resource is bootstrapped');
    }
    $userAgent = $bootstrap->getResource('useragent');
    if ($userAgent->getBrowserType() === 'mobile') {
         echo "mobile";
    }
    else
    {
       echo "others";
    }
```

I am getting the following warning :                                                                                            "PHP Warning:  include_once(): Failed opening 'Zend/Http/UserAgent/Device/Features/Browscap.php' for inclusion (include_path='/.../application/../library:/.../library:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /.../library/Zend/Loader.php".
But If I refresh the page the warning disappears.
Any help will be appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: I know this might not be that 'helpful' of an answer, but have you tried upgrading to the most recent 1.12 branch of ZF?  I'm writing that test code in that version and do not receive the error.  If at all possible, give that a shot, and then see if it's still a problem.  Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks Aaron Saray for your suggestion.I have upgraded ZF to the latest version 1.12 but by doing so it does not load the mobile view, when I select the user agent as Android Mobile.

Comment: You say it doesn't load the mobile view - well what is the userAgent resource saying in this case?  Is WURFL loading properly now?  If you give more info, I can help out.